# "Cannot read property 'className' of null " - Once you scroll past the headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, gantt-chart

Recreating the problem.

Go to:

http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/

And paste the following code into console.

```
$('.dataPanel').on('click', function(e) {
    var elm = $(this);
    $('.row.desc').children().filter(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().top < e.pageY && ($(this).offset().top + 25) > e.pageY) {
            console.log($(this).html());
        }
    });
    $('.row.date').filter(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < e.pageX  && $(this).offset().left + 25 > e.pageX ) {
                console.log($(this).html());
            }
    });
});
```

Now click at some empty space in gantt chart. Console will output the day that is clicked and appropriate description.

The problemem arises once you scroll down the page just to hide day date headers and then click on empty space.

Like so

[image: Example]

Following error will get thrown.

```
jquery.fn.gantt.js:386 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null
```

What's causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error @ `jquery.fn.gantt.js:386` is being thrown in the original lib already, your code didn't break it. That error has something to do with [document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) where it looks like the lib is trying to get an element that is "outside the visible bounds of the document or either coordinate is negative" so "the result [will be] null". The error is thrown as the script tries to read the class name of this null value.

To fix that error in the library,  I would try and just change line 384 into `var col = core.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY);`

Also..

You can by pass this error by unbinding the libraries event listeners, and your code will no longer throw this error. You should be able to simple do it like:

```
$('.dataPanel').unbind('click').on('click', function(e) {
    /* the rest of your code */
});
```

Then no errors will be printed and your code will run:

```
$('.dataPanel').unbind('click').on('click', function(e) {
    var elm = $(this);
    $('.row.desc').children().filter(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().top < e.pageY && ($(this).offset().top + 25) > e.pageY) {
            console.log($(this).html());
        }
    });
    $('.row.date').filter(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < e.pageX  && $(this).offset().left + 25 > e.pageX ) {
                console.log($(this).html());
            }
    });
});
[<div class=​"dataPanel" style=​"width:​ 8352px;​ margin-left:​ 0px;​ height:​ 312px;​">​…​</div>​]
 Warranty Period
   <div class="fn-label">14</div>
 Showcasing
   <div class="fn-label">6</div>
 Development
   <div class="fn-label">8</div>
 Scoping
  <div class="fn-label">9</div>
```